# Setting up an RSS Feed (to use for podcasting with iTunes) that reads information from a mysql database (using php)

Tags: php, rss, itunes

I have an RSS feed that I have iTunes linked to to use for podcasting (all this works). However, I am trying to set it up so that I don't have to hardcode each podcast data into the RSS feed. So my method of doing this has been using a podcast upload form which loads all the data into a mysql database and then use a "for" loop in php to read it out into the feed. Getting the data from the form into the database works perfectly and connecting and reading from the database works also. However, when I try to implement this into the RSS feed, there are no "articles" that show up. Here is the code to the .rss file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<rss xmlns:itunes="http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd" version="2.0">
<channel>
<title>Victory Central Church Message Podcast</title>
<link>http://www.vc2online.com</link>
<language>en-us</language>
<copyright>&#x2117; &amp; &#xA9; 2012 Waller Hill Publishing</copyright>
<itunes:subtitle>Victory Central Church Podcast</itunes:subtitle>
<itunes:author>Victory Central Church</itunes:author>
<itunes:summary>The Sermons from Victory Central Church - A regional church sharing the life-giving message of Jesus Christ with Central Georgia and the world!</itunes:summary>
<description>The Sermons from Victory Central Church - A regional church sharing the life-giving message of Jesus Christ with Central Georgia and the world!</description>
<itunes:owner>
<itunes:name>Victory Central Church</itunes:name>
</itunes:owner>
<itunes:image href="images/podcasts_logo.jpg" />
<itunes:category text="Christianity">
<itunes:category text="Spirituality"/>
</itunes:category>

<?php

    $host = 'xxx.xx.xxx.xxx';
    $username = 'xxxx';
    $password = 'xxxx';
    $database = 'xxxx';

    mysql_connect($host, $username, $password) or die( "Unable to connect.");
    @mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database.");

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  `podcasts` WHERE 1 LIMIT 0 , 30");

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo "<item>";
        echo "<title>" . $row['title'] . "</title>";
        echo "<itunes:author>" . $row['author'] . "</itunes:author>";
        echo "<itunes:subtitle>" . $row['subtitle'] . "</itunes:subtitle>";
        echo "<itunes:summary>" . $row['summary'] . "</itunes:summary>";
        echo "<itunes:image href=\"" . $row['imageurl'] . "\" />";
        echo "<enclosure url=\"" . $row['url'] . "\" type=\"" . $row['type'] . "\" />";
        echo "<guid>" . $row['guid'] . "</guid>";
        echo "<pubDate>" . $row['date'] . "</pubDate>";
        echo "<itunes:duration>" . $row['duration'] . "</itunes:duration>";
        echo "<itunes:keywords>" . $row['keywords'] . "</itunes:keywords>";
        echo "</item><br><p />";

    }

?>

</channel>
</rss>
```

Of course the host, user, password, and database are included in the actual code. No errors are displayed when I run this code as it is. Only no "articles" show up. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You ensured that your webserver treats your .rss file as a file that contains PHP code that will be parsed and executed?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not entirely sure what you mean by that.

Comment: Often a webserver is configured so that only files ending with ".php" will be pushed through the PHP parser. You mentioned that your file ends with ".rss". Are you certain that your web server evaluates the PHP script within the file?

Comment: If "yes", then check your PHP error log.

Comment: Well, I have tried rewriting the file 3 ways, with a .php, .rss, and .xml (with the appropriate coding) and none of them worked. If the server does not allow that then would the .php also not write rss?

Answer (score 0):

I've created a small open source library for this.

You can download and learn how to use it [here](https://github.com/read2me-online/itunes-podcast-feed-php), but let me c/p an example nonetheless:

```
use iTunesPodcastFeed\Channel;
use iTunesPodcastFeed\FeedGenerator;
use iTunesPodcastFeed\Item;

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

// SETUP CHANNEL
$title = 'Read2Me Daily Curated Articles';
$link = 'https://read2me.online';
$author = 'NYTimes and Medium';
$email = 'hello@read2me.online';
$image = 'https://d22fip447qchhd.cloudfront.net/api/widget/static/images/default-thumbnail.png';
$explicit = false;
$categories = [
    'News',
    'Technology',
    'Culture',
    'Entrepreneurship',
    'Productivity'
];
$description = 'Daily curated articles from New York Times and Medium';
$lang = 'en';
$copyright = 'The New York Times Company and The Medium Company';
$ttl = 43200; // 12 hours in seconds

$channel = new Channel(
    $title, $link, $author, $email,
    $image, $explicit, $categories,
    $description, $lang, $copyright, $ttl
);

// SETUP EPISODE
$title = "Trump Says Disclosure of Mueller Questions in Russia Probe Is ‘Disgraceful’";
$fileUrl = 'https://s3.read2me.online/audio/www-nytimes-com-2018-05-01-us-politics-trump-mueller-russia-questions-html-7e9601.mp3';
$duration = '2:18';
$description = 'WASHINGTON — President Trump on Tuesday said it was “disgraceful” that questions the special counsel would like to ask him were publicly disclosed, and he incorrectly noted that there were no questions about collusion. The president also said collusion was a “phony” crime.';
$date = 1525177808;
$filesize = 828387;
$mime = 'audio/mpeg';

$item = new Item(
    $title, $fileUrl, $duration,
    $description, $date, $filesize, $mime
);
$item2 = clone $item; // just to give you an idea of how it works

// SETUP FEED
$feed = new FeedGenerator($channel, ...[$item, $item2]);

// OUTPUT XML
header('Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8');

print $feed->getXml();
```